# Python Static Typing Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

Python is dynamically typed, so it can store different types. This makes code easier to write, but also slower.

I'm aware that stuff like Cython exists. However, it is possible to use just python (inbuilt functions or some library) that would allow us to use static type variables, in order to make code run faster?

Comment: It's not clear why you think duck typing impacts performance.

Comment: I mean dynamically typed, not duck typed.

Answer (score 1):

> Python is dynamically typed, so it can store different types. This makes code easier to write, but also slower.

You seem to assume that Python is slow *because* of its dynamic nature. I'd say that belies a fundamental misunderstanding: speed and performance are *not* features of the language but of its implementations. Yes, the attributes of a language might make it easier or harder to write a performant implementation — but that only matters to those implementing the language.

As an example, several very fast implementations of JavaScript exist. Simply put, some very clever people put quite a lot of effort into wringing every little bit of performance out of it — even though doing so was very hard due to the idiosyncrasies of the language and its highly dynamic nature. As a result, many now consider it a “fast” language.

So, why is Python slow? Probably because you're using its reference implementation, CPython, which is indeed a rather slow and straightforward interpreter. PyPy, on the other hand, offers a modern Just-in-Time compiler, making raw, repetitive Python code run *much* faster.

Oh, and even the implementations of “fast” languages perform many tricks nowadays, whether performing compilation ahead of time or not. There's nothing straightforward about what a C compiler or the JVM does to make code run fast.

(Lua might be a different case, but I don't know all that much about it.)

Answer (score 0):

The NumPy package is statically typed [1].  Also, NumPy supports a greater number of data types than Python[2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).

[1]: Chin, L, Dutta, T. NumPy Essentials (Kindle Location 360). Packt Publishing. Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](https://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/11/08/why-is-python-slow/), you can improve speed in many cases by being more specific about your classes and their data-members, and using JIT-capable implementations like PyPy. Thus, according to the author of the blog, you can specify your class better such as the following:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y', 'width', 'height')

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height = x, y, width, height
```

This would make the code run slightly faster, since depending on python implementation, the interpreter may this info to use better underlying data structures.